# Plot continuous width legend denoting edge weight

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx, legend, graph-theory

I am creating a network graph with the networkx package and the width of the edges is on a continuous scale (in this example it is a correlation value), which works fine. But I am having trouble with creating a legend for this.

Before I had the correlation value visualized by a continuous grey colormap and I had the colorbar as the legend. My question is now: Is there a possibility to create something like the colorbar but for the width of my edges? It should look like a long triangle i would think.

Answer (score 1):

One way in which this could be achieved is as follows. Note that it does not produce a continuous triangle as you described, but instead evaluates the width of the edges at equally spaced points and adds these to a discrete legend.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import networkx as nx

# Number of lines to include in legend
NUM_INTERVALS = 6

# Set up random graph with random weights
G = nx.Graph()
for i in range(50):
    G.add_edge(random.randint(1,10), random.randint(1,10), weight = random.uniform(0,8))
pos = nx.circular_layout(G)

# Get weights from graph
weights = [G[s][e]['weight'] for s, e in G.edges()]

# Get evenly distributed points over range of weights
lines = np.linspace(min(weights), max(weights), NUM_INTERVALS)

# Create lines from the weights
line2ds = [Line2D([],[], linewidth=width, color='black') for width in lines]

# Draw graph
nx.draw(G, pos, width=weights)

# Draw legend (rounding decimals to 2 places)
legend2 = plt.legend(line2ds, np.round(lines, decimals=2), bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1))
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that's the way I did it in the end, because i could not figure the legend out but thanks anyway! Should be good enough i think :D